# How to use firebase just for authentification and use nodejs as backend?

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm developping a flutter application, and I want to use firebase just for authentification, and use NodeJs for all other backend service (content filter by users).
I don't know if that possible, if It possible, how to validate if someone has logged in or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is totally possible and supported.

Once you've signed the user in, you'll need to [get their ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) and then pass that to your backend through a secure connection. On that backend you can then [verify if the ID token is valid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and determine what the user is authorized to do to your custom backend.

Comment: Thanks Frank your response was very helpfull, and clear